# How do I get table structure with Bootstrap dropdown

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

[Using span instead of table element][1]
[Using the table element][2]

I'm using Bootstrap 5 and what I'm trying to accomplish is use a table instead of dropdown menu items. I want that table to be fixed width so that hopefully I can position the text in the 3rd column to the far right. Then the date in that column and the dropdown arrows will all be horizontally aligned to the same place so it looks like the dropdown arrows are all on top of each other.

If I use span instead of table everywhere, then I get what looks like in image 1. However, if I use the table like in my code below, then I get what looks like in image 2. The dropdown arrows, for some reason, get moved to the left. How do I get them to move to the right? I'd like to be able to use table elements so that I can position the cells. Thanks.

````
<div class="col-md-12 dropdown" id="premiumsDropdownBtn">
   <div class="dropdown-toggle dropend" role="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
   <table>
      <td>Dental: </td>
      <td class="position-relative">PLAN A<span class="dropdown-arrow"></span></td>
      <td style="text-align: right;">1/1/2023 - NA</td>
   </table></div>
<div class="dropdown-toggle dropend" role="button" id="dropdownMenu3" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
   <table>
      <td>Dental: </td>
      <td class="position-relative">PLAN B</td>
      <td style="text-align: right;">1/1/2023 - NA</td>
   </table></div>
<div class="dropdown-toggle dropend" role="button" id="dropdownMenu4" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
   <table>
      <td>Vision: </td>
      <td class="position-relative">TEST PLAN C<span class="dropdown-arrow"></span></td>
      <td style="text-align: right;">1/1/2023 - NA</td>
   </table></div>
<div class="dropdown-toggle dropend" role="button" id="dropdownMenu5" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
   <table>
      <td>Vision: </td>
      <td class="position-relative">LONGER PLAN D<span class="dropdown-arrow"></span></td>
      <td style="text-align: right;">1/1/2023 - NA</td>
   </table></div>
</div> ```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbXmj.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2EAw.png
````

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there are a few issues in your code. Here's a corrected version:

- Wrap the content of each dropdown toggle in a `<tr>` (table row) element.
- Place the `<tr>` inside a `<table>`.
- Ensure that each `<td>` (table cell) is inside a `<tr>`.

```html
<div class="col-md-12 dropdown" id="premiumsDropdownBtn">
    <div class="dropdown-toggle dropend" role="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Dental: </td>
                <td class="position-relative">PLAN A<span class="dropdown-arrow"></span></td>
                <td style="text-align: right;">1/1/2023 - NA</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown-toggle dropend" role="button" id="dropdownMenu3" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Dental: </td>
                <td class="position-relative">PLAN B<span class="dropdown-arrow"></span></td>
                <td style="text-align: right;">1/1/2023 - NA</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown-toggle dropend" role="button" id="dropdownMenu4" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Vision: </td>
                <td class="position-relative">TEST PLAN C<span class="dropdown-arrow"></span></td>
                <td style="text-align: right;">1/1/2023 - NA</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown-toggle dropend" role="button" id="dropdownMenu5" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Vision: </td>
                <td class="position-relative">LONGER PLAN D<span class="dropdown-arrow"></span></td>
                <td style="text-align: right;">1/1/2023 - NA</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```